# C++ include error with a precompiled header

Tags: c++, header-files, precompiled-headers

I've to include the Intel Open Image Denoise (https://openimagedenoise.github.io/index.html) to work with my current c++ project. I have this project with it's own CMakeFiles and structure, with the main file in the app directory and other directories like scripts, tests etc. Libraries are in the libs directory, so the structure is like

```
-app
 |-main.cpp
-libs
  |-lib1
  |-lib2
  |-oidn
  |-CMakeFile.txt
-otherFolders
-CMakeFile.txt
```

Now in the libs folder I have the "oidn" folder which I downloaded from the website and it is the PRECOMPILED version. The structure is

```
-oidn
 |-bin (binaries)
 |-doc (documentation)
 |-include
 | |-OpenImageDenoise (what I actually need)
 |   |-oidn.hpp
 |   |-oidn.h
 |   |-version.h
 |-lib
 | |-cmake (folder with .cmake files)
 | |-libOpenImageDenoise.so
 | |-libOpenImageDenoise.so.0
 | |-libOpenImageDenoise.so.1.2.0
 | |-libtbb.so.2
```

Now what I want is to be able to use this library, calling it inside the main. I've added in the main

```
#include <OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp>
```

but VSCode tells me to update the includePath. I have done it and now no erros form VSCode that also suggests me code. But when i go building with CMake, it wont building raising the error

```
fatal error: OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Why it is not finding the library? Is it not possible to use a precompiled version? Should I include something in the CMakeFile.txt?

Comment: Use double quotes, `#include "OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp"`.

Comment: Same, doesn't work

Comment: Depending on how your INCLUDE search paths are set up, you may need to specify the full path from the source file to the header file.

Comment: I think its not finding the `OpenImageDenoise` folder in your include directories.